# Spring boot quartz: jdbc tables are always initailized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, quartz-scheduler

We are using quartz in spring boot application.
For storing job information, I have used jdbc store.
In `application.properties` file, I have following:

```
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

But after every restart, tables are initialised, and all stored info is lost.
If I change spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema to never, I get exception while creating tables.

I do not want to delete quartz table data after restart.
Can you help me ?

Regards,
Stephan

Comment: So what else do you expect. That is exactly what you have instructed to happen.

Comment: To avoid initialising of tables, i changed setting to                 
  spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=never.    But then, i get exception and tables are not generated.

Answer (score 11):

Well, according to the docs:

> By default, the database is detected and initialized by using the
> standard scripts provided with the Quartz library. These scripts drop
> existing tables, deleting all triggers on every restart. It is also
> possible to provide a custom script by setting the
> spring.quartz.jdbc.schema property.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html

What you could do:

1. Modify the scripts that quartz uses to create the tables and remove the drop table statements and use `create table if not exists...`: https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/tree/main/quartz/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore
2. Put the statements into a script in your `src/main/resources` directory somewhere (assuming you're using maven)
3. Set the `spring.quartz.jdbc.schema` to point to your file created in #2

Since you can use any database, the scripts are going to be database specific.

OR

An alternative is to use flyway/liquibase and use the above scripts as a change in those management systems (this is personally what I would do)

Scripts -

For example, mysql is here (you'd want to remove the drop table statements at the beginning and follow the steps above to use custom init scripts):

```
#
# Quartz seems to work best with the driver mm.mysql-2.0.7-bin.jar
#
# PLEASE consider using mysql with innodb tables to avoid locking issues
#
# In your Quartz properties file, you'll need to set
# org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_LOCKS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_TRIGGERS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_CALENDARS;


CREATE TABLE QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS
  (
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    JOB_NAME  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    JOB_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    JOB_CLASS_NAME   VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    IS_DURABLE VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    IS_NONCONCURRENT VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    IS_UPDATE_DATA VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    REQUESTS_RECOVERY VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    JOB_DATA BLOB NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ_TRIGGERS
  (
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    JOB_NAME  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    JOB_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    NEXT_FIRE_TIME BIGINT(13) NULL,
    PREV_FIRE_TIME BIGINT(13) NULL,
    PRIORITY INTEGER NULL,
    TRIGGER_STATE VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_TYPE VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    START_TIME BIGINT(13) NOT NULL,
    END_TIME BIGINT(13) NULL,
    CALENDAR_NAME VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    MISFIRE_INSTR SMALLINT(2) NULL,
    JOB_DATA BLOB NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (SCHED_NAME,JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP)
        REFERENCES QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS(SCHED_NAME,JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS
  (
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    REPEAT_COUNT BIGINT(7) NOT NULL,
    REPEAT_INTERVAL BIGINT(12) NOT NULL,
    TIMES_TRIGGERED BIGINT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
        REFERENCES QRTZ_TRIGGERS(SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS
  (
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    CRON_EXPRESSION VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TIME_ZONE_ID VARCHAR(80),
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
        REFERENCES QRTZ_TRIGGERS(SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS
  (
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    STR_PROP_1 VARCHAR(512) NULL,
    STR_PROP_2 VARCHAR(512) NULL,
    STR_PROP_3 VARCHAR(512) NULL,
    INT_PROP_1 INT NULL,
    INT_PROP_2 INT NULL,
    LONG_PROP_1 BIGINT NULL,
    LONG_PROP_2 BIGINT NULL,
    DEC_PROP_1 NUMERIC(13,4) NULL,
    DEC_PROP_2 NUMERIC(13,4) NULL,
    BOOL_PROP_1 VARCHAR(1) NULL,
    BOOL_PROP_2 VARCHAR(1) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
    REFERENCES QRTZ_TRIGGERS(SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS
  (
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    BLOB_DATA BLOB NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
        REFERENCES QRTZ_TRIGGERS(SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ_CALENDARS
  (
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    CALENDAR_NAME  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    CALENDAR BLOB NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,CALENDAR_NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS
  (
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS
  (
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    ENTRY_ID VARCHAR(95) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    INSTANCE_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    FIRED_TIME BIGINT(13) NOT NULL,
    SCHED_TIME BIGINT(13) NOT NULL,
    PRIORITY INTEGER NOT NULL,
    STATE VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    JOB_NAME VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    JOB_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    IS_NONCONCURRENT VARCHAR(1) NULL,
    REQUESTS_RECOVERY VARCHAR(1) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,ENTRY_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE
  (
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    INSTANCE_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    LAST_CHECKIN_TIME BIGINT(13) NOT NULL,
    CHECKIN_INTERVAL BIGINT(13) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,INSTANCE_NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE QRTZ_LOCKS
  (
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    LOCK_NAME  VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,LOCK_NAME)
);


commit;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have googled and found that below combination is recommended, and works also:
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=never. So, i want to know that why it is not working in my case. Do we have to configure something else also ?

Comment: You have to create the database tables, if you set the schema to 'never' quarts isn't going to create it for you. So yet, set it to never and then make sure the tables get created somehow (go re-read my answer for 2 different ways how)

Comment: Thanks. I am working as per your suggestions. I have defined file quartz_tables.sql in resouces. In application.properties, i assign it value  classpath: /quartz_tables.sql. But this file is not being picked up. Can you help further ?

Comment: @Stephan That's a separate question - ask it as its own and post more details

Comment: hello Mibek, i have posted it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64132063/how-to-assign-db-script-to-spring-quartz-jdbc-schema

Comment: ok - typically you'd mark the answer given as correct if it answers your question (the checkmark above)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it follows recommandations and even links to the repository with standard scripts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did the following steps for Spring boot to get it running perfectly.

I created the schema manually called "quartz". Then created all the tables manually by copying the correct script from https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/tree/master/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore

Then I have the following properties in the spring boot properties file:

```
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=quartz.QRTZ_
```

All the other properties I set are as follows:

```
#==============================================================
# QUARTZ Configuration
#==============================================================
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=25
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=5
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread=true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=quartz.QRTZ_
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=5000
```

Comment: How access the blob field job_data of table qrtz_job_details into the executing job?

Answer (score 0):

I did the same. I used the solution 1) however, since i wanted everything to be created automatically. I created a file in my resources `quartz/schema.sql` and set the property `spring.quartz.jdbc.schema: classpath:quartz/schema.sql`.

For reference, here is my script for PostgreSQL 9:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS
(
    SCHED_NAME        VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    JOB_NAME          VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    JOB_GROUP         VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION       VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    JOB_CLASS_NAME    VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    IS_DURABLE        BOOL         NOT NULL,
    IS_NONCONCURRENT  BOOL         NOT NULL,
    IS_UPDATE_DATA    BOOL         NOT NULL,
    REQUESTS_RECOVERY BOOL         NOT NULL,
    JOB_DATA          BYTEA        NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, JOB_NAME, JOB_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_TRIGGERS
(
    SCHED_NAME     VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_NAME   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    JOB_NAME       VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    JOB_GROUP      VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION    VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    NEXT_FIRE_TIME BIGINT       NULL,
    PREV_FIRE_TIME BIGINT       NULL,
    PRIORITY       INTEGER      NULL,
    TRIGGER_STATE  VARCHAR(16)  NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_TYPE   VARCHAR(8)   NOT NULL,
    START_TIME     BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    END_TIME       BIGINT       NULL,
    CALENDAR_NAME  VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    MISFIRE_INSTR  SMALLINT     NULL,
    JOB_DATA       BYTEA        NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (SCHED_NAME, JOB_NAME, JOB_GROUP)
        REFERENCES QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS (SCHED_NAME, JOB_NAME, JOB_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS
(
    SCHED_NAME      VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_NAME    VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    REPEAT_COUNT    BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    REPEAT_INTERVAL BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    TIMES_TRIGGERED BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP)
        REFERENCES QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS
(
    SCHED_NAME      VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_NAME    VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    CRON_EXPRESSION VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    TIME_ZONE_ID    VARCHAR(80),
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP)
        REFERENCES QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS
(
    SCHED_NAME    VARCHAR(120)   NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_NAME  VARCHAR(200)   NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR(200)   NOT NULL,
    STR_PROP_1    VARCHAR(512)   NULL,
    STR_PROP_2    VARCHAR(512)   NULL,
    STR_PROP_3    VARCHAR(512)   NULL,
    INT_PROP_1    INT            NULL,
    INT_PROP_2    INT            NULL,
    LONG_PROP_1   BIGINT         NULL,
    LONG_PROP_2   BIGINT         NULL,
    DEC_PROP_1    NUMERIC(13, 4) NULL,
    DEC_PROP_2    NUMERIC(13, 4) NULL,
    BOOL_PROP_1   BOOL           NULL,
    BOOL_PROP_2   BOOL           NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP)
        REFERENCES QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS
(
    SCHED_NAME    VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_NAME  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    BLOB_DATA     BYTEA        NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP)
        REFERENCES QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_CALENDARS
(
    SCHED_NAME    VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    CALENDAR_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    CALENDAR      BYTEA        NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, CALENDAR_NAME)
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS
(
    SCHED_NAME    VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS
(
    SCHED_NAME        VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    ENTRY_ID          VARCHAR(95)  NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_NAME      VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP     VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    INSTANCE_NAME     VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    FIRED_TIME        BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    SCHED_TIME        BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    PRIORITY          INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    STATE             VARCHAR(16)  NOT NULL,
    JOB_NAME          VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    JOB_GROUP         VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    IS_NONCONCURRENT  BOOL         NULL,
    REQUESTS_RECOVERY BOOL         NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, ENTRY_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE
(
    SCHED_NAME        VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    INSTANCE_NAME     VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    LAST_CHECKIN_TIME BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    CHECKIN_INTERVAL  BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, INSTANCE_NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QRTZ_LOCKS
(
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    LOCK_NAME  VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, LOCK_NAME)
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_J_REQ_RECOVERY
    ON QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS (SCHED_NAME, REQUESTS_RECOVERY);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_J_GRP
    ON QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS (SCHED_NAME, JOB_GROUP);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_T_J
    ON QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, JOB_NAME, JOB_GROUP);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_T_JG
    ON QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, JOB_GROUP);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_T_C
    ON QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, CALENDAR_NAME);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_T_G
    ON QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_T_STATE
    ON QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_STATE);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_T_N_STATE
    ON QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP, TRIGGER_STATE);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_T_N_G_STATE
    ON QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP, TRIGGER_STATE);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_T_NEXT_FIRE_TIME
    ON QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, NEXT_FIRE_TIME);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_T_NFT_ST
    ON QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_STATE, NEXT_FIRE_TIME);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_T_NFT_MISFIRE
    ON QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, MISFIRE_INSTR, NEXT_FIRE_TIME);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_T_NFT_ST_MISFIRE
    ON QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, MISFIRE_INSTR, NEXT_FIRE_TIME, TRIGGER_STATE);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_T_NFT_ST_MISFIRE_GRP
    ON QRTZ_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, MISFIRE_INSTR, NEXT_FIRE_TIME, TRIGGER_GROUP, TRIGGER_STATE);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_FT_TRIG_INST_NAME
    ON QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, INSTANCE_NAME);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_FT_INST_JOB_REQ_RCVRY
    ON QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, INSTANCE_NAME, REQUESTS_RECOVERY);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_FT_J_G
    ON QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, JOB_NAME, JOB_GROUP);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_FT_JG
    ON QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, JOB_GROUP);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_FT_T_G
    ON QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_QRTZ_FT_TG
    ON QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP);
```

Comment: Do we need seperate table script for each database.... For MySQL, postgresql do we need seperate scripts?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't use MySQL that much, but I think some of the syntax is different, so it might require 2 scripts still.

Comment: Yes. But some column like varchar(1) is changed to Boolean in postgres (eg isdurable column in quartz_job_detail) ..why they don't keep same varchar(1) in postgres also.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below property from application.properties & your Quartz table data won't be deleted on every restart.
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).