# how to assign db script to spring.quartz.jdbc.schema

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz with spring boot. I want to use own db script to generate quartz tables during startup. I have generated tables_postgresql.sql file and put in src/main/resources.
In application.properties, i assign value to
spring.quartz.jdbc.schema = \tables_postgresql.sql.

But it is not being picked up during start up.
Can you please help me how to use this sql file during statrt up ?

Regards, Stephan

Comment: I have also tried it with spring.quartz.jdbc.schema = classpath: /tables_postgresql.sql. (as per documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). But it does not work.

Comment: Do you have the other properties such as spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc and spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always ?

Comment: In addition, i have following settings: spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema= always                                                 
  spring.quartz.jdbc.comment-prefix=#    i haver also changed schema file settings to  spring.quartz.jdbc.schema =classpath:sql/quartz_tables.sql    But it gives exception :

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [sql/quartz_tables.sql]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [sql/quartz_tables.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist  .   I have also changed to   :        classpath: quartz_tables.sql   ,                                                               
 /quartz_tables.sql     ,         \quartz_tables.sql   , classpath: resources/quartz_tables.sql .          But no luck. Can you please help me further ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, I hope it helps others...
I created the file (that contains the create tables/idx statements):

```
src/main/resources/quartz.sql
```

And I configured the `application.properties` like this:

```
spring.quartz.jdbc.schema=classpath:quartz.sql
```

since the file is in the "resources" folder, it should not have a "/" (slash) or blank spaces.